# Supress a single warning message in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, warnings, backend, suppress-warnings

In order for production code to run on machines with different python installations it needs to call

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
```

This is super annoying because it throws the warning

> warnings.warn(_use_error_msg)
>   /home/keith/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py:1312: UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
>   because the backend has already been chosen;
>   matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
>   or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

on some of the machines. I would like to suppress this **and only this** message. I know I can call

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

but this might cause me to miss other warnings.

--------------Edit---------------

I have found what may be a solution but I am unsure

```
import warnings
import matplotlib as mpl
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    mpl.use('Agg')
```

Comment: Why are you unsure? Does it work?

Comment: Read the warning and fix what it's warning you about! The `mpl.use` call *isn't doing anything*, because of where it is in relation to your other imports.

Comment: @user2357112 On other machines there is no warning because it does something. jonrsharpe I no longer get the message but am unsure if this is doing other things. In short does this only affect code inside the "with"?